# CURL 403 Forbidden Error but working good in POST man request

Tags: bash, api, rest, ubuntu, curl

**Issue:** Curl command not giving response with `200` status but If I send request from postman its working fine
Here I have shared the CURL command.

Any suggestion to resolve this issue would be appreciated

```html
curl --location --request GET '<domain_url>' \
--header 'Authorization:'
```

Comment: POSTMAN may have a stored cookie that's needed for auth; just saying - also unsure if your local machine is whitelisted but where your serving the call it might not; don't leave any stones unturned you'll find it.

Comment: @IlanP Thank you for your reply. I verified log in AWS for CURL API request. The IP in the log showing as `yyy:yyy:yyy:yyy:yyyy:yyy:yyy:yyyy`. Its different one from actual IP I have whitelisted.  I think this might cause the issue. But don't know why AWS log capturing my IP in different pattern

Comment: Ah so I guess you discovered your issue - You may want to consider whitelisting IPv6 formats as it seems that's the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @IlanP. I solved this problem by adding --ipv4 like `curl --ipv4 https://example.org/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue by using option `--ipv4` in curl request since `ipv4` whitelisted in server.

```html
curl --ipv4 https://example.org/
```